# Expressão regular que retorna palavras próximas

Tags: python, regex

Bom eu estou trabalhando em uma expressão regular que pega placas de veículos, meu interesse seria não pegar apenas as placas, mas como coisas próximas a ela, por exemplo:

```
|Placa:AVX-4300 Fiat Uno |
```

Aqui esta a expressão que eu estou usando `[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}`, quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: Qual é o formato do texto que você vai executar a regex? Todos são nesse formato: |Placa:AVX-4300 Fiat Uno |?

Comment: sim, sao todos no formato de uma linha apenas, queria delimitar o numero de palavras proximas que ele pega.

Comment: Mas todas as linhas seguem um formato definido? Se não, não serão regulares e, portanto, regex não é solução. Se sim, qual exatamente é o formato? Sempre terá a marca e nome do veículo?

Comment: Sempre tera sim.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar esta regex:

```
[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}\s\w+\s\w+
```

Apenas acrescentei `\s\w+\s\w+` que irá capturar junto da placa mais duas *strings* (contendo letras, números ou *underscore*) consecutivas separadas por espaço (`\s`).

Caso queira incluir um hífen na busca, seria:

```
[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}\s[\w-]+\s[\w-]+
```

**[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/sAj7yr)**

Comment: Mas o `\w` já pega letras e números.

Comment: nao tem problema pegar letras e numeros, ta bom po.

Comment: como ficaria para pegar antes tbm

Comment: Antes do número da placa? Pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: altere `\s[\w-]+\s[\w-]+` por `((?:\s[\w-]+)*)`, assim você cria um grupo apenas para esta informação, além de deixar opcional e ilimitado, a quantas palavras forem necessárias. [Veja em REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/KoYfIa/1)

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert No Python retorna apenas  "Fiat Uno "